# How can i create nested functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create "nested functions". But i can't seem to find a solution!

```
const func1 = (value1) => {
  const func2 = (value2) => {
    console.log(value1 + value2)
  }
}

func1(2).func2(3)
```

What i really want to accomplish is create my own little "jQuery function"

```
const $ = (element) => {
  const addClass = (name) => {  
    const x = document.querySelectorAll(element);
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].className = name
    }
  }
}

$('#circle').addClass('nice')
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: the term you are looking for is called "function chaining" - what you are doing right now is nowhere near what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: `func1(2).func2(3)` – Here `func1()` **returns an object** which has a method `func2`…

Comment: you have to return this :)

Comment: Can someone provide an example where "func1(2).func2(3)" is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this topic is too broad for a single SO question, but here is a very simple example of how you could do this, to get you started:

```js
const $ = (selector) => {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

  const self = {
    addClass: (name) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].classList.add(name);
      }

      return self;
    },
    removeClass: (name) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].classList.remove(name);
      }

      return self;
    }
  };

  return self;
}

$('#circle').addClass('nice').removeClass('bad');
```

```css
.nice {
  color: green;
}
.bad {
  color: red;
}
.fancy {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id='circle' class='bad fancy'>
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you! What is this called exactly? :)

Comment: I don't know of a specific name for the code structure above, but the term for calling one method after another like that is called "method chaining" or a "[fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)."